# Dividir Coluna em Outras duas Lat Long

Tags: string, r

Possuo a seguinte planilhas de dados:

```
  BIRDS.GENERO         SP1        SP2                       XLOCAL
  Thamnomanes      caesius    glaucus                0°32'S52°12'W 
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis                0°10'S51°50'W
  Thamnomanes      caesius    glaucus         00°53'44"N52°00'08"W 
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis         00°53'44"N52°00'08"W 
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W
  Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi   03°58'14,82"S49°52'56,37"W
  Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi   03°58'14,82"S49°52'56,37"W
  Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi     03°31'46,9"S51°44'05,2"W
  Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi     03°31'46,9"S51°44'05,2"W
```

Gostaria de dividir a coluna **XLOCAL** em Latitude e Longitude. Assim:

```
 BIRDS.GENERO         SP1        SP2             XLOCAL                   Lat            Long
 Thamnomanes      caesius    glaucus                0°32'S52°12'W         0°32'S        52°12'W
 Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis                0°10'S51°50'W         0°10'S        51°50'W
 Thamnomanes      caesius    glaucus         00°53'44"N52°00'08"W     00°53'44"N     52°00'08"W
 Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis         00°53'44"N52°00'08"W     00°53'44"N     52°00'08"W 
 Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W        01°40'N        51°23'W
 Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W        01°40'N        51°23'W
 Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi   03°58'14,82"S49°52'56,37"W  03°58'14,82"S  49°52'56,37"W 
 Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi   03°58'14,82"S49°52'56,37"W  03°58'14,82"S  49°52'56,37"W
 Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi     03°31'46,9"S51°44'05,2"W   03°31'46,9"S   51°44'05,2"W
 Thamnomanes      caesius hoffmannsi     03°31'46,9"S51°44'05,2"W   03°31'46,9"S   51°44'05,2"W
```

Pesquisando no fórum achei algo parecido com isso:

```
dados$lat<- str_sub(dados$XLOCAL, end = 6)
head(x)
dados$long<- str_sub(dados$XLOCAL, start  = 7)
```

Como podem perceber há uma grande variação do tamanho das informações. Logo o argumento acima não funciona.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Seu script tem de ser inteligente o suficiente para pesquisar pela letra S. Se achar copia do inicio até o S e do caracter após o S até o final. Se não achar, copia do inicio até a letra N e após o N até o final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar `strsplit` para separar as coordenadas, aproveitando a opção de "olhar para trás" de expressões regulares. Porque strsplit retorna uma lista, o mais prático é primeiro jogar o resultado para um objeto e depois incluir cada coluna no data.frame original.

```
dados <- read.table(text = c(
 "BIRDS.GENERO         SP1        SP2                       XLOCAL
  Thamnomanes      caesius    glaucus                0°32'S52°12'W 
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis                0°10'S51°50'W
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W
  Thamnomanes   ardesiacus  obidensis               01°40'N51°23'W"),
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

listaC <- strsplit(dados$XLOCAL, "(?<=N|S)", perl = TRUE)
dados$Lat  <- unlist(lapply(listaC, '[', 1))
dados$Long <- unlist(lapply(listaC, '[', 2))

> dados
  BIRDS.GENERO        SP1       SP2         XLOCAL     Lat    Long
1  Thamnomanes    caesius   glaucus  0°32'S52°12'W  0°32'S 52°12'W
2  Thamnomanes ardesiacus obidensis  0°10'S51°50'W  0°10'S 51°50'W
3  Thamnomanes ardesiacus obidensis 01°40'N51°23'W 01°40'N 51°23'W
4  Thamnomanes ardesiacus obidensis 01°40'N51°23'W 01°40'N 51°23'W
```

Answer (score 2):

Não consegui uma solução direta, utilizei a função `separate` do pacote `tidyverse` duas vezes e fiz algumas manipulações nas variáveis resultantes para chegar no resultado que você espera.

Sendo `dados` seu banco, segue código:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  separate("XLOCAL", into = c("Lat1", "Long1"), sep = "N", remove = F, extra = "drop", fill = "right") %>% 
  separate("XLOCAL", into = c("Lat2", "Long2"), sep = "S", remove = F, extra = "drop", fill = "right") %>% 
  mutate( Lat1 = paste0(Lat1, "N"), Lat2 = paste0(Lat2, "S") ) %>% 
  mutate( Long2 = ifelse(is.na(Long2), "", Long2), Long1 = ifelse(is.na(Long1), "", Long1) ) %>% 
  mutate( Lat = ifelse(Long1 == "", Lat2, Lat1), Long = paste0(Long2, Long1) ) %>% 
  select(BIRDS.GENERO:XLOCAL, Lat, Long)
```

- o primeiro `separate` está quebrando `XLOCAL`, em duas variáveis (`Lat1` e `Long1`), pelo separador `N`;
- o segundo `separate` está quebrando `XLOCAL`, em duas variáveis (`Lat2` e `Long2`), pelo separador `S`;
- o primeiro `mutate` está incluindo os indicadores `N` e `S` as variáveis `Lat1` e `Lat2`, respectivamente, já que a função `separate` exclui os separadores usados;
- o segundo `mutate` está modificando o que é `NA` para um campo em branco;
- o terceiro `mutate` está criando as variáveis `Lat` e `Long` utilizando as variáveis "auxiliares" `Lat1`, `Lat2`, `Long1`, `Long2`;
- por fim, a função `select` está selecionando as variáveis de interesse